# How to use a List that is populated in another project

Tags: c#

Can i populate a List in one project and use the same list with the same objects in another project?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Make it `static public`?

Comment: Please give some more details so we might be able to come up with something better that to just mark it static.

Comment: Are we talking about different projects in the same solution/application or are we talking different applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declared it as global,

```
static public List<Type> name;
```

Comment: Thats a bad habit to teach a new programmer. You should encourage Object Orented design and tell them to pass the class that holds the list around instead of having a shared static object.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But OPs requirement might differ

Comment: and since we don't know OPs requirement this is a dangerous answer. Better to ask OP for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Project A, which create a list
Propject B which want to use it

Create method in project A which create and return a list

```
public class SharedList
{
    public List<T> GetMyList()
    {

    }
}
```

Then use this method in the Project B

```
var lists = new ProjectB.SharedList();
List myList = lists .GetMyList()
```

If you don't care about future growth of your application then make this method static.